# Fluent NHibernate reference FK with whitespace value

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm attempting to map two tables in a legacy system (Jet db) that cannot be changed. The child table has a FK to a string type column in the parent table. The FK column in the parent table is required but will often be whitespace i.e. ' '. I know this makes no sense but this is what I have to deal with. The mapping I have is;

```
        References(x => x.ParentObject)
              .Formula("NOT ParentFKColumn = ' '")
              .Column("ChildFKColumn")
              .LazyLoad()
              .Nullable();
```

This mapping results in the following exception "illegal access to loading collection : Input string ' ' was not in the correct format". The error seems obvious enough - I'm just not sure how to deal with it Fluently.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

i assumed the string type column in the parent table is not the primary key hence you need to map it as `property` and use `property-ref`.

```
 References(x => x.ParentObject)
          .PropertyRef("stringProperty")
          .Column("ChildFKColumn")
          .Not.LazyLoad()      // to prevent creating invalid Proxies, but property-ref should already do this
          .NotFound.Ignore(); // threat all values in the foreign key which
```

`.NotFound.Ignore();` tells NH to threat all values in the foreign key which do not point to a valid record as null.